# Add macro to \chapter command

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I am using the report class. And all I want that after the use of `\chapter{...}` the marco `\thispagestyle{onlypagenumber}` is added.

I fixed this with just defining a new macro `\Chapter{...}`

`\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{\chapter{#1}\thispagestyle{onlypagenumber}}`

However I would rather like to still use `\chapter{...}` since people are used to typing `\chapter{...}` instead of `\Chapter{...}`. How can I make this small alteration? Note also that `\thispagestyle{onlypagenumber}` should not be added to star chapters e.g. `\chapter*{...}`

I tried also using the [etoolbox](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) which provides the some of "appto" commands on page 9.

> \appto This command appends arbitrary hcodei to a hhooki. If the
>   hcodei contains any parameter characters, they need not be doubled.
>   This command is robust.

This failed however but probably I am doing something wrong. I would prefer a solution of the etoolbox.

Example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{onlypagenumber}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhfoffset[RO,EL]{2.5cm}
  \fancyhead[OR]{%
    \sffamily
    \quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad
    \thepage
  }
  \fancyhead[EL]{%
    \sffamily\thepage
    \quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad
  }
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhfoffset[OR,EL]{2.5cm}
\fancyhead[OR]{%
  \sffamily\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}
  \quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad
  \thepage
}
\fancyhead[EL]{
  \sffamily\MakeUppercase{\thepage}
  \quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~\thechapter
}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

\newcommand{\Chapter}[1]{\chapter{#1}\thispagestyle{onlypagenumber}}

\begin{document}

\Chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-40]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to patch `\chapter`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{onlypagenumber}{}{}
```

because `\chapter` does `\thispagestyle{plain}` and the patch will replace `plain` with `onlypagenumber`.

However, an easier way is just doing

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhfoffset[RO,EL]{2.5cm}
  \fancyhead[OR]{%
    \sffamily
    \quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad
    \thepage
  }
  \fancyhead[EL]{%
    \sffamily\thepage
    \quad\smash{\rule[-.2ex]{1pt}{4cm}}\quad
  }
}
```

so as to redefine the `plain` page style, instead of defining a new one: you probably don't need the plain page style any more, do you?

---

For changing the style only for numbered chapters, use

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thispagestyle{onlypagenumber}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

so that `\thispagestyle{plain}` issued by `\chapter` will be countermanded when `\@makechapterhead` (which is executed only for numbered chapters) is processed.

Comment: If I use the `patchcmd` it also replaced the page style of chapters with a star (`\chapter*{...}`) which I do not want. And I cannot use the plain pagestyle since I already have defined that.